# Prevent JsonSerializer.Deserialize Converting Null to String

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to to deserialize a string using `System.Text.JsonSerializer.Deserialize`

```
private Document GetDocumentMessageObject(string objectString)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Document>(objectString, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});
        }
```

However, it converts `null` to an empty string

```
public async Task GetDocument()
    {
        string message = null;
        var documentMessage = $"{{\"message\": \"{message}\" }}";
        var value = GetDocumentMessageObject(documentMessage);

        //Continue code

    }
```

How can I prevent converting `null` to an empty string?

Comment: In your example the JSON message property isn’t null. Your JSON is `{ "message": "" }`. For message to be null it must be `{ "message": null }`.

Comment: @ckuri But I want to use string interpolation. I don't want to use `null` in the JSON

Comment: Is there any reason you can't jest new up the `Document` i.e. `var value = new Document {Message = null};`?

Comment: @GuruStron It actually is part of a test case. That's why I can't use `null` there. It's a Unit Test with different Test Case, but I summarize the question to this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it converts null to an empty string

No, it does not, your resulting json contains empty string for message if `message` variable is `null` - `{ "message": "" }` so it is correctly deserialized to empty string. You need to build a correct json, quick and dirty approach would be using anonymous object:

```cs
var documentMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { message = (string?)null });
```

Or build the json string correctly manually:

```cs
var documentMessage = $"{{\"message\":{(message is null ? "null" : $"\"{message}\"")}}}";
```

Or using C# 11 raw string literals:

```cs
var documentMessage = $$"""
{
   "message":{{(message is null ? "null" : $"\"{message}\"")}}
}
""";
```